# How can I parse data from .swf file?

Tags: flash, parsing

I'm trying to develop an application that will parse the data from a .swf (I want to be able to read some fields from the flash file) How can I achieve this? or is it impossible ?

Comment: It's possible, but only using a Flash decompiler.

Comment: In what language are you trying to parse the .swf file ?

Comment: You'll need to check specifications for the swf file format, then parse the binary file content. Try: http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SWF::Parser

Ex:

```
use SWF::Parser;

  $parser = SWF::Parser->new( 'header-callback' => \&header, 'tag-callback' => \&tag);
  # parse binary data
  $parser->parse( $data );
  # or parse SWF file
  $parser->parse_file( 'flash.swf' );
```

Check here: http://search.cpan.org/~ysas/SWF-File-0.42/lib/SWF/Parser.pm