# node.js swf extraction definebitslossless2 incorrect pixels

Tags: javascript, node.js, flash

I made an library to extract **images** and **binary** (`.bin`) data from an **SWF** File.

But for `DefineBitsLossless2` tag (`PNG` images with alpha), I have a problem: some pixels aren't at their right place, but the others are **OK**.

Here's my current code (written in `Typescript`) using [Jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) library for image manipulation (I also tried `node-canvas`, same thing)

```
private async DefineBitsLossless2(buff: SWFBuffer, tag: any, tagHeader: any, Callback: Function) {
        var id     = buff.readUIntLE(16);
        var format = buff.readUInt8();
        var width  = buff.readUIntLE(16);
        var height = buff.readUIntLE(16);

        var data   = buff.buffer.slice(buff.pointer, (buff.pointer + tagHeader.length) - 7);
                     buff.addPointer(tagHeader.length - 7);

        if(format != 5) {
            throw new Error(`Unsupported DefineBitsLossless2 image format. Only format 5 is supported, got format ${format}`);
        }

        var GZBuffer = this.concatSWFHeader(zlib.unzipSync(data), data);
        var image    = await new Jimp(width, height);
        var position = 0;

        for(var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for(var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                var alpha = GZBuffer.readUInt8(position++);
                var red   = GZBuffer.readUInt8(position++);
                var green = GZBuffer.readUInt8(position++);
                var blue  = GZBuffer.readUInt8(position++);

                image.setPixelColor(Jimp.rgbaToInt(red, green, blue, alpha), x, y);
            }
        }

        image.getBuffer(Jimp.MIME_PNG, function(err, buffer) {
            tag.id     = id;
            tag.format = format;
            tag.width  = width;
            tag.height = height;
            tag.data   = buffer;
            Callback(null);
        });
    } 



private concatSWFHeader(buff: Buffer, swf: Buffer) {
    return Buffer.concat([swf.slice(0, 8), buff]);
}
```

Here's the result of [this SWF](http://habboo-a.akamaihd.net/dcr/hof_furni/48082/fball_ptch5.swf) that I used for test pruposes:

Using my **library**:

[image: #1]

Using **FFDec** (Free Flash Decompiler in Java)

[image: #2]

I followed [**this Adobe** **guide**](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf) to make my library (see the page `144` for `DefineBitsLossless2` tag)

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373304/how-can-i-parse-data-from-swf-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this:

```
var GZBuffer = this.concatSWFHeader(zlib.unzipSync(data), data);
```

should instead be:

```
var GZBuffer = zlib.unzipSync(data);
```

Not sure what you were going for with `concatSWFHeader`, but that would rather be part of the ZLIB header you're adding, and it should account for whole image being offset by 2 pixels.

Comment: Working! Thank youu